# Android google map api

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, key

If you sign with your own api key for the google maps will it work while your device is in debug mode to test it or will your personal api key only work when the device is live on the market?

So will my personal api key only work once my app is live on the market. I can't test my own api key out before i publish ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation :

> You can get a temporary Maps API Key based on your debug certificate,
>   but before you publish your application, you must register for a new
>   Key based on your release certificate and update references in your
>   MapViews accordingly

Comment: You can install your app via adb install or sent it to your gmail and install it from there.

Comment: do i send the apk to my email

Answer (score 1):

Will work only on the market...for debugging you must get fingerprint of your debug.keystore.
You find here more details.
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Comment: So it won't work while im testing thanks for the answer so fast man.

Answer (score 1):

If you sign with the android keystore, the app will only work while debugging. In order your app to be able to operate correctly when published, the map key should be signed with the official keystore of the app (the one you create when exporting your application).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Not only on the market. Either you install it from the market or via adb install, the app you created using the public keystore will work with the map api key.

Comment: Will installing it from eclipse onto my phone by pressing run while my device is in debug mode is that an adb install??

Comment: Nop, you have to execute the command adb install 'your apk' from the platform-tools folder.

Comment: Ok so my personal api key won't work unless i download it from the market or do an adb install